# Make predicitions with model in R after using sandwich package

Tags: r, model, prediction, poisson

I've tried to create a reproducible example of what I'm working with:

```
data <- 
  starwars %>% 
  mutate(sex = if_else(sex == "male", 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(sex)) %>% 
  select(sex, height:birth_year)

model <- 
  glm(sex ~ ., 
    family = poisson(link=log),
    data = data, 
    na.action = na.omit)
```

After this I'm getting robust standard errors using the sandwich estimator:

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

coeftest(model, vcov = sandwich)
```

This gives me this result:

```
z test of coefficients:

                          Estimate  Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             -20.958054    1.026481 -20.4174 < 2.2e-16 ***
height                   -0.822054    0.035631 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
mass                      2.944574    0.127630  23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
hair_colorblack        -448.140311   19.424331 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
hair_colorblond        -462.427356   20.043593 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
hair_colorbrown        -456.721023   19.796256 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
hair_colorbrown, grey  -553.841217   24.005864 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
hair_colorgrey         -427.919006   18.547853 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
hair_colornone         -440.465772   19.091684 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
hair_colorwhite        -422.256239   18.302404 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorbrown          56.611334    1.651011  34.2889 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorbrown mottle  320.776467   12.802880  25.0550 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colordark          -45.044692    3.250161 -13.8592 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorfair          -37.593846    2.944552 -12.7673 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorgreen         302.140802   11.997764  25.1831 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorlight         -57.115326    3.751430 -15.2249 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colormetal         192.177639    8.449005  22.7456 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colororange        387.570078   15.690788  24.7005 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorpale          394.492839   15.990251  24.6708 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorred           387.306647   15.679392  24.7016 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colortan           -28.711918    2.585760 -11.1039 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorunknown       -41.368616    3.098941 -13.3493 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_colorwhite         240.664687    9.345035  25.7532 < 2.2e-16 ***
skin_coloryellow         -5.070099    1.436846  -3.5286 0.0004177 ***
eye_colorblue           441.829184   19.150780  23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
eye_colorbrown          437.122834   18.946786  23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
eye_colorhazel          435.130198   18.860417  23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
eye_colororange          57.572275    2.495430  23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
birth_year               -0.325727    0.014118 -23.0711 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My doubt is that when I want to get predictions of my model with new data, is it okay if I do it without the robust standard errors? In that case I would do it like this (starwars2 is made up):

```
predict(model, newdata = starwars2, type = "response")
```

But how do I include robust standard error to make new predictions?

*Note: I'm working with a poisson model instead of a binomial because with this you get the RP instead of the odds. It´s widely use in epidemiology.*